# How to allow resubscription in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, subscriber, unsubscribe

I have created a custom one-click unsubscribe page, through which a user can unsubscribe from the campaign.Is there any way that we can allow re-subscription of that user. Or what are the re-subscription ways?

Below is the code that I used to Unsubscribe :

```
%%[

var @debug
var @jid
var @listid
var @batchid
var @email
var @skey
var @reason
var @unsubscribeAll

set @debug = 0
set @jid = RequestParameter("JobID")
set @listid = RequestParameter("ListID")
set @batchid = RequestParameter("BatchId")
set @email = RequestParameter("Email")
set @skey = RequestParameter("SubKey")
set @reason = "One-Click Unsubscribe"
set @unsubscribeAll = "1"

/* if we know the subscriber */
if not empty(@skey) then

   var @lue
   var @lue_prop
   var @lue_statusCode
   var @overallStatus
   var @requestId
   var @Response
   var @Status
   var @Error

   /* if unsubscribing from all, then set the job, batch and listids to blank, effectively doing a global unsub */
   if @unsubscribeAll == "1" then
     set @jid = ""
     set @listid = ""
     set @batchid = ""
   endif

   /* create a request to inject an unsub event into the LogUnsubEvent platform table */
   set @lue = CreateObject("ExecuteRequest")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue,"Name","LogUnsubEvent")

   /*
    In order to invoke the request, we need to associate the following information with it to define the subscriber context and the job context:

    1. Subscriber Key
    2. JobId associated with the email send
    3. ListID the email was sent to
    4. BatchID the email was sent to
    5. Reason for the unsub
   */

   /* 1. define and associate Subscriber Key to the request */
   set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @skey)
   AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

   /* 2. define and associate JobID to the request */
   if not empty(@jid) then
    set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "JobID")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @jid)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)
   endif

   /* 3. define and associate ListID to the request */
   if not empty(@listid) then
     set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
     SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "ListID")
     SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @listid)
     AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)
   endif

   /* 4. define and associate BatchID to the request */
   if not empty(@batchid) then
    set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "BatchID")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @batchid)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)
   endif

   /* 5. define and associate unsub reason to the request */
   set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "Reason")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @reason)
   AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

   /* finally, you invoke the request */
   set @lue_statusCode = InvokeExecute(@lue, @overallStatus, @requestId)

   /* extract messages from the response */
   set @Response = Row(@lue_statusCode, 1)
   set @Status = Field(@Response,"StatusMessage")
   set @Error = Field(@Response,"ErrorCode")

endif

if @debug == 1 then
  output(concat("<br>jid: ", @jid))
  output(concat("<br>listid: ", @listid))
  output(concat("<br>batchid: ", @batchid))
  output(concat("<br>email: ", @email))
  output(concat("<br>skey: ", @skey))
  output(concat("<br>reason: ", @reason))
  output(concat("<br>unsubscribeAll: ", @unsubscribeAll))
  output(concat("<br>overallStatus: ", @overallStatus))
  output(concat("<br>requestId: ", @requestId))
  output(concat("<br>Response: ", @Response))
  output(concat("<br>Status: ", @Status))
  output(concat("<br>Error: ", @Error))
endif

]%%
```

Comment: Please provide more context. Are you referring to the status in All Subscribers? Are you managing your opt-ins in a data extension?

Comment: If you did it using SOAP you could just use the same code but you should change the status to 'Active' instead of 'Unsubscribed'. Also, it would be nice if you put the code used for it here.

Comment: @LukasLunow I am referring to the status in All Subscribers

Comment: @DarleisonRodrigues I've updated my question with my code

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to make a specific customer **ACTIVE** or **UNSUBSCRIBED**.
But make sure to be on the process how do you wish them to be re-subscribed! As you are NOT supposed/can send send emails to the customers who had Unsubscribed! [from a particular list/publication].

```ampscript
<!-- Custom unsub page for single/ multi list-->
%%[
    SET @sub_key = RequestParameter("subkey")
    SET @email = RequestParameter("email")
]%%
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1.1.5"); 
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var options = {SaveOptions: [{'PropertyName': '*', SaveAction: 'UpdateAdd'}]};

//getting values from AMPSCRIPT variables to SSJS variables
var subscriberkey = Variable.GetValue("@sub_key");
var email = Variable.GetValue("@email");
var myPubLists = [{mid:'xxxx', listID:'xxxx'}];

function unsub(obj) 
{ prox.setClientId({ "ID": obj.mid }); //This will switch BU contexts
  var props = { SubscriberKey: subscriberkey,
                EmailAddress: email,
                Lists: [{ ID: obj.listID, Status: 'Unsubscribed'}]// to unsub = "Unsubscribed" to subscribe = "Active"
              };
  var data = prox.updateItem("Subscriber", props, options);
  prox.resetClientIds(); //This will reset BU context
  return data.Results[0].StatusCode;
}

for (var i=0; i<myPubLists.length; i++)
{
    var result = unsub(myPubLists[i]);
    Write("Result:" + result);
}
</script>
Received value subkey = %%=v(@sub_key)=%%
<br/><br/>
Hello Customer, your email address %%=v(@email)=%% has been unsubscribed/re-subscribed.
```